# Is this a correct proof that an isomorphism between two cyclic groups always maps a generator to a generator of the other group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

The solution I obtained was different to the answers I've seen online, but I wanted to ask if it is correct.

The exact statement to be proven is

> **Let $(G, \Delta)$ be a cyclic group and $(F, \nabla)$, and let $\psi : G \to F$ be an isomorphic function. If $G = \langle g \rangle$, then prove that $\psi(g)$ generates $F$.**

My proof was as follows:

First consider $\psi(g)$, a necessary and sufficient condition for this to generate $F$ is that for every $f \in F$, there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$
\begin{align}
f
&= \big(\psi (g)\big)^k \\
&= \underbrace{\psi(g) \nabla \psi(g) \nabla ... \nabla \psi(g)}_{\text{$k$ times}} \\
&= \psi(\underbrace{g \Delta g \Delta ... \Delta g}_{\text{Also $k$ times}}) & \text{That this follows from the previous step can be proven more rigorously by induction.} \\
&= \psi\left(g^k\right)
\end{align}
$$

As $\psi$ is bijective, it is also surjective, and thus there must exist $c$ such that $f = \psi (c)$. Because $g$ generates $G$, we can say that some $m$ exists such that $c = g^m$, and thus that $f = \psi(c) = \psi\left(g^m\right)$ which means that this $k$ (equal to $m$) exists for all $f \in F$.

Is this proof correct? I'm a bit unsure, because I saw that many people prove it with a proof by exhaustion (they consider the case where $k < 0$, $k = 0$, and $k > 0$ seperately - I recognise that by proof doesn't cover the case for $k < 0$, but I think that as there exists a bijection between the natural numbers and the integers it might be possible to "map" integers to natural numbers - or I might be talking nonsense).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Right after "My proof was" it should be "for every $f \in F$" rather than your "for every $x \in F$" [since you go on and show for $f$]

Comment: Thanks for the catch (I wasn't really sure which letter to pick there and accidentally ended up picking multiple)!

Comment: With the edited verion it's correct. It may be longer than necessary...

Comment: The proof is correct. Though such bijections between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, it wouldn't be helpful here. For any homomorphism $\phi$, $\phi(e)=e$ and $\phi(g^{-m}) = \phi(g)^{-m}$ (try proving this if you haven't seen it already). Thus, you can painlessly generalise to $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Lastly, note that your proof can easily be modified to show that for any isomorphism, the image of a generating set is a generating set.

Answer (score 2):

Homomorphisms have the property that $\lvert h(g)\rvert\mid \lvert g\rvert $ for any $g$ (try proving this using the homomorphism property). Since an isomorphism has an inverse,  we also have $\lvert h^{-1}( h(g))\rvert =\lvert g\rvert \mid\lvert h(g)\rvert $.

Thus $\lvert i(g)\rvert =\lvert g\rvert $ for any isomorphism and element $g$.

That's isomorphisms preserve order. This is a more general fact.

Comment: An even more general argument works here. Isomorphism preserves any property that can be defined using only the group axioms. The order of an element is such a property.

Comment: Sure, and,  this happens alot.  It's mathematicians' favorite thing to do.   @EthanBolker