# What does it mean when a proof of a theorem actually proves a stronger result?

Tags: soft-question, definition

Many times, in math textbooks, the author says something along the lines of, "This proof of the theorem actually proves a stronger result...". I am a little confused as to what that means, formally. Formally, a proof is a sequence of either axioms or justified steps, culminating in the last step, which is called a theorem. So, I am a little confused what authors of math textbooks actually mean by that. It can't simply be something like, "Theorem $S$ implies theorem $S'$", because in a theory $T$, every theorem implies every other theorem in that theory. So, my real question is, has anyone formalized what it means for a proof of a theorem to actually prove a stronger result than the theorem itself? Or, is this, in fact, one of those notions in math books which has no adequate formalization, and is just one those things that are "You know them when you see them"?

Comment: It's not Theorem S implies Theorem S'. It's more like: To prove Theorem S, we prove Theorem S' which implies Theorem S (but then only Theorem S is stated, perhaps because it is more useful compared to Theorem S' (which is stronger) )

Comment: would help if you gave some specific examples.

Comment: When you prove something you learn something, and when you learn something you may realize that you can prove more things.

Comment: I'd need to see a specific example, but it's probably pedagogical.  You actually have a proof $P$ of $S'$, but you first label it as a proof of $S$, because $S$ is perhaps more natural, or more simply stated.  But then after the reader sees the proof $P$, they are better prepared to see the statement of $S$.  This also matches the way research is often done - we start with trying to prove a statement $S$, but in the process, prove something more general $S'$.

Comment: I second the request for examples, and moreover think that a question asking about all instances of an incredibly common turn of phrase, and one that can be used in several dofferent ways, is unreasonably broad. It's somewhat akin to asking for a definition of uniform definition of *normal* that encompasses both subgroups and distributions.

Comment: This is not a formal statement. The author is saying that, from the given proof of $S$, the reader should be able to easily construct a proof of $S'$, even though it looks like $S'$ should be harder to prove.

Answer (score 5):

Let's suppose that the theorem you *intended* to prove was this:

**Theorem:** $P$ implies $Q$.

And let's say that the proof went like this:

*Step 1:* $P$ implies $X$

*Step 2:* $X$ implies $Q$.

**QED**

But now someone thinks to ask: In Step 2, is the converse true? In other words, does $Q$ imply $X$? And they notice: No! $Q$ does not imply $X$.

In that case the proof of the theorem actually proves a stronger result: the implication $P \implies X$ is *stronger than* the implication $P \implies Q$.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite common with complete induction. You want to proof A(n) for all natural numbers n. To do this you prove A(0) and you proof that A(n) implies A(n+1). And sometimes this doesn’t work because A(n) does almost but not quite imply A(n+1).

As an example, say you want to show that f(n) <= n. But f(n+1) is a tiny bit larger than f(n)+1, so the induction step doesn’t work.

However if you take the stronger statement f(n) <= n - 1/n, you might be able to prove that because f(n+1) may now be a tiny bit larger than f(n)+1, and the induction step still works.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the theorem is a *corollary* of an in essence different result.

The different result is *stronger* or more general.

Here's a perfect example,  from my own work: [group isomorphisms preserve element order](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4587281/1070376)